Model files not opening with Cura after removing old version
After installing a newer version of Cura and uninstalling the prior version, Windows still tries to open files set to use Cura with the old version. Since the that file no longer exists, Windows asks which app to use:

The old app is still in the list, but the new one is not. Attempting to use "ultimaker-cura.exe" results in the same dialog opening again asking which app to use!
Using the Default Apps list in Windows does not offer to use the new Cura version.

This sounds more like a Windows issue rather than a 3D printing issue.

@agarza It's both. It's specifically a problem related to "updating" the Cura slicing software on Windows because Cura does not actually "update" like 99% of apps out there. Instead, you simply install a new version, leaving multiple versions installed, and you are left to manually uninstall the prior version. Anyone that uses Cura on Windows may run into this issue, and a web search shows I'm not the only one. If you check this S.E. help section, you'll see software is on-topic. I could have put it in SuperUser, but I thought 3D printing is really the best audiences because... 3D printing.

I'm not sure what causes this to happen, but the solution is to manually edit the registry.
Open Registry Editor and go to:
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Applications\UltiMaker-Cura.exe\shell\open\command


From there, edit the data to point to the new Cura exe, which will likely just be a different version number in the directory.
